# Html Video as background

Tags: html, css

In my website there is a problem with video background. it's not going to fixing all page. my video is in 1080p but it's not going to fix all page i want same video ass full page without sliding it.
video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmWXXKlv1jo
main:

```
<html>
<head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="./smoke.css">
</head>
<body>
   
  <video id="videodiff" autoplay muted loop>

              <source src="smoke.mp4"  type="video/mp4">

              </video>

            >
</body>


</html>
```

css:

```
#videodiff {
    position:fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    #videodiff {
        width:100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    #videodiff {
        width:auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #videodiff {
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: are you looking for a `parallax scrolling` effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the following parameters of your video ID `#videodiff`

```css
#videodiff {
   position: fixed;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #videodiff {
        display: none;
    }
} // You were missing this "}" aswell
```

This will make it so the html item with this ID is attached to the whole screen by default and have a `z-index` value smaller than default, so it is in the background.

I don't think this portion of code is needed:

```css
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    #videodiff {
        width:100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    #videodiff {
        width:auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```